# spring security: authentication by session from backend another application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I created my backend on spring boot and I used standard spring session authentication. I see, that spring after success auth marks my session id as authenticated.

On the other service I have simple spring boot application, which serves an angular application. In this application I tried to create a controller which sends a request to my backend with resttemplate and after success auth, redirect to root "/", where controller serve application.

I tried to parse headers "set-cookie" from resttemplate response and manually add to cookie browser, but in browser created new session between angular and my backend and user isn't authenticated.

I know that I can send request from angular application and this will be work, but for my plans I have to authenticate user from spring on server and after redirect to angular
Have anybody done this or have any ideas for resolving this task?

This is my try but it didn't work:

```
    private Cookie createSessionCookie(ResponseEntity<?> response) {
    Cookie cookie = null;
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        String headerKey = "Set-Cookie";
        List<String> headerValue = response.getHeaders().get(headerKey);
        if (headerValue != null && !headerValue.isEmpty()) {
            String[] sessionKeyValue = headerValue.get(0).split(";")[0].split("=");
            cookie = new Cookie(sessionKeyValue[0], sessionKeyValue[1]);
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            cookie.setDomain(backend.getDomain());
            cookie.setPath(backend.getPath());
            log.info("Auth successful -> session: {}", cookie.getValue());
        }
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

Comment: OAuth2 solves this problem.  You authenticate against one server, which will give your angular app an access token, then you use that token when calling services in the other server.

Comment: @httPants I know, that I can use JWT auth and I will solve this problem, but I want to know any solution for session auth